# Yelp.com blocked from my work address

Tags: blocking

Yelp.com is blocked from my work internet.  Not by any filtering on the part of the office (it is a shared office building with shared internet.) My wild guess is Yelp banned the range of IP addresses from the office because maybe some other tenant here was abusing the site?  Or maybe some DNS or something else is just whacky and broken?  It is nothing on my laptop, the same laptop can access Yelp.com fine from my home internet.

I find it annoying, how could I get Yelp unblocked?  It's been this way for 6 months or so.  I just want to look up a restaurant to order lunch from and I can't, just annoying.  How could I figure out why Yelp is inaccessible? (the only site I've seen that shows up as "Forbidden: No access on this server".)  How could I get around this access block?

Comment: For your connection is this through the 3G connection or through WiFi?

Comment: How do you know that the site is blocked? What exactly happens when you try to access it?

Comment: @Manni: *Forbidden: No access on this server*...?

Comment: Wow. OK. In that case, I'd try to contact their support from home and see what happens.

Comment: you can use google translater like proxy sometimes it helps)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How could I get around this access
>   block?

Your options:

1. You can setup a VPN connection,
   [using](http://lifehacker.com/5361872/hotspot-shield-13-works-with-hulu-again-sometimes) a software like [Hotspot
   Shield](http://hotspotshield.com/)
2. You can use [TOR](http://www.torproject.org/) [Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2275)
3. You can use online proxy services like [Kproxy](http://www.kproxy.com), [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/)
4. You can mail Yelp support and find why is it that the IP is banned.

Comment: I'd definitely start with the last option.

Comment: @innaM It's worth noting that yelp doesn't respond to either emails or phone calls.

Answer (score 2):

Go through the Google servers. Google has an option to format any page for mobile devices. Just use http://www.google.com/gwt/n?u=http://yelp.com. It doesn't look pretty, but it has a chance of working.

This works with any web page; just replace yelp.com with whatever you want. All links going from that page will still be formatted for mobiles. This also has the advantage of reducing web traffic; all images seem to be compressed automatically by Google. If you don't want images either, just append `&_gwt_noimg=1` at the end of the URL above.

Comment: My work blocks based on text strings in the entire URL with HTTP variables even, so this doesnt work for me.

Comment: @Good Time Tribe just use http://www.google.com/gwt/n?u=yelp.com then.

Answer (score 2):

Does the [Yelp Iphone](http://download.cnet.com/Yelp-for-iPhone/3000-2379_4-10863636.html) app work?

Comment: Yeah, that works for me.  But it is not as convenient as the website.

Answer (score 0):

> Or maybe some DNS or something else is just whacky and broken?

If (today) `yelp.com` resolves to `65.87.22.19` then your DNS is fine...

To get around it: use some (optionally web-based) [proxy server](http://hidemyass.com)?